# Android camera controls

Tags: android, android-camera

Is it possible to use camera controls like in default Camera app? I've implemented my camera app as described [here](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/43414.aspx), but still can't figure how to add these controls.

Answer (score 1):

Camera parameters are viewed and modified through Camera.Parameters. Example (assumes mCamera is a camera instance):

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
```

//View and modify parameters by calling the get/set parameters for the parameter you're interested in. Then call setParameters to commit the changes.

```
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

Camera.Parameters contains get/set parameters that allow you to view and modify camera features. Camera.Parameters also contains methods that allow you to query the camera to see what values a given parameter will accept.  For example, to determine what preview sizes the camera will accept you call getSupportedPreviewSizes() like this:

```
List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
```

Other camera parameters have similar design patterns.
Review the Camera.Parameters documentation here for more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html

Comment: Thanks, Ryan! So, as i understood, i should add all UI elements, which will control camera params by myself? Where is no way to add default UI controls? (like flash-on/off switcher, etc)

Comment: I'm not aware of default UI controls for the camera. Sorry.